# Launching vim with a servername

Tags: terminal, clientserver

I am trying to use reverse searching from PDF documents to their respective *.tex files. I use vim (in terminal) as my editor and my PDF viewer is Zathura. Forward searching works however the problem with reverse searching is that vim requires a server name to be defined so that zathura can send it commands.

Is it possible to configure vim so that when running `vim name.tex` in terminal it will automatically define a server name which is `'name'`? Essentially, I would like to make it so `vim name.tex` runs as if I had input `vim name.tex --servername name`. Is such a thing possible? I am aware that the server name cannot be defined once vim is running and needs to be part of the terminal command, however I am not experienced with this sort of thing.

EDIT: After some testing if I run `vim --servername vim` in multiple terminals and then run `vim --serverlist` in another I notice that all the servers have the name VIM followed by the number. So for example if I have four terminals open and run `vim --servername vim` in each and open a fifth terminal and run `vim --serverlist` it returns,

```
VIM
VIM1
VIM2
VIM3
```

With this if I have `set synctex-editor-command 'vim --remote-silent +%{line} %{input}'` in my `zathurarc` by `<C-left click>` it will reverse search to the appropriate line of my TeX code in the server with lowest numbered `VIM` servername. So if I close the server `VIM` and the remaining servers `VIM1`, `VIM2`, and `VIM3` are still open the the reverse search will bring up the TeX code in `VIM1`. So essentially this simplifies the problem to just having a script which executes `vim name.tex --servername vim`.

**SOLUTION**

This solution is due to statox and as such I have marked him as having solved it. I simply tinkered with his idea to get the final product. For any of those who pass and are in need of a solution in `~/.bashrc` place the following

```
alias vimsn='vim-with-servername'

vim-with-servername() {
vim --servername 'vim' "$@"
}

alias vim=vimsn
```

After doing this restart your terminal. Running `vim file.type` in terminal will now run `vim --servername vim file.type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that needs to be done before vim is started what about using a bash alias?

In your `~/.bash_alias` file (or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`) you could add the following:

```
alias vimsn='vim-with-servername'

vim-with-servername() {
# Check we have one argument and it ends with .tex
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [[ ! "$1" =~ "\.tex$" ]]; then
    echo 'Usage'
    echo 'vimsn filename.tex'
    return 1
fi

# Remove .tex from the filename
servername=${1%.tex}

# Start vim with the servername
vim $1 --servername $servername
}
```

Then when youll need to open vim the way you describe it you can use the following command:

```
vimsn name.tex
```

And that should actually run

```
vim name.tex --servername name
```

Comment: I tried your solution just now and I get the error: `bash: vimsn: command not found`. I tried placing this in `~\.bashrc` and `~/zshrc`. I did not have `~/.bash_alias` but I created it and I encountered the same error as above. I have added an edit to my original post which seems to simplify the problem.

Comment: So 1) if you put it in `~/.bash_aliases` (there was a typo in my answer) you need to source this file in your shell rc file 2) If you put it in your shell rc file you need to put it only in the corresponding file either `~/.bashrc` if you use bash, `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh or another file if you use another shell 3) you need to source your rc file again to have the alias available, the easiest way to do that is to close and reopen your terminal after you modified your rc file 4) regarding your edit you can modifiy the function a bit to use `'vim'` instead of the variable `$servername`

Comment: Ok so following your advice vimsn now works but only returns `Usage` and `vimsn filename.tex` however it does not run vim with the desired server name. Sorry I have very little idea of what the script is doing.

Comment: No problem, I tried to be explicit in the comments but that wasn't enough :) So the `if` checks two things: 1) that you gave an argument to your command 2) that is argument ends with `.tex` so if you call `vimsn` with more than one file or with a path which doesn't end in `.tex` you will get the `Usage` message. How do you call `vimsn`?

Comment: I would call it as `vimsn Notes.tex` where `Notes.tex` is a specific file of mine. I played around with your code and simply putting `vim 1 --servername 'vim'` within `{}` works. So by this I mean, `vim-with-servername(){ vim $1 --servername 'vim'}`

Comment: Great if you came up with a solution! Don't hesitate to post your own answer with the solution you're going with and mark it as accepted to show future reader that a solution exists :)

Comment: I have marked you as a solution due to the significant contribution you made. Without it I would not have been able to resolve the issue. Thanks. Out of curiosity though, why does it fail to work when trying to make it to select out the filename as the servername?

Comment: I have no idea why it fails for you because it works on my machine (™)... Maybe try to remove the `if` altogether, then add just the condition on `[ "$#" -ne 1 ]` to see if it works to only validate invocations with only one argument, then try with the other part `[[ ! "$1" =~ "\.tex$" ]]` to check if the pattern matching works. You could also `echo $# $1` to see the number of argument received (that's `$#`) and the first argument received (`$1`) and see if something isn't right... Maybe `=~` isn't posix and you use an "exotic" shell. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey statox, I ended up coming back to this and getting it to work. However, now I have the issue of getting Zathura with the appropriate servername for the instance of vim running the .tex file. So if I open filename.tex in vim, that instance of vim will have a server name filename. Am I able to configure Zathura so that it will detect the filename it has opened and make it the server name for the inverse search when I `<C-left click>`?

Comment: Hi @Zeta-Squared I don't know anything about Zathura so I can't answer your question. Maybe [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) know more about this tool (check in their help center if this is on topic I don't know) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/)? But this doesn't seem to be about vim anymore :)